# How to load json data into mongodb on spring startup?

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot

While I use postgresql and with the jpa, I will use this line  `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`
But now Iam using mongodb and data file is `data.json`.Now how would I do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the JSON data using MongoDB compass or MongoDB CLI. And then you can use the mongo connection string to use the database on Spring boot.

The connection string would be available on MongoDB Atlas.

https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/spring-boot

Comment: No, that's not my question. I have a json file with insert query inside it and it should run on string boot startup and load the data into mongodb database.